# enum class of Base class reference as underlying type

Tags: c++

I know that the underlying type of an enum class should be an integral. Is it possible to define an enum class with a Base class reference as underlying type?

```
class CInt {
public:
    CInt() = default;
    virtual ~CInt() = default;

    virtual void fun1() = 0;
    virtual void fun2() = 0;
};

class A : public CInt {
    A() : CInt() {};
    ~A() = default;

    void fun1() {
        std::cout << "A fun1" << std::endl;
    }

    void fun2() {
        std::cout << "A fun2" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B : public CInt {
    B() : CInt() {};
    ~B() = default;

    void fun1() {
        std::cout << "B fun1" << std::endl;
    }

    void fun2() {
        std::cout << "B fun2" << std::endl;
    }
};

// the below code doesn't compile
enum class ClassType : CInt& {
    A_Type, // class A object reference
    B_Type // class B object reference
};
```

Comment: what you want to do with it?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: The long answer is also:  No.  However, there are several strategies for working around the language limitation.  Which strategy depends on what you are trying to do (XY problem; have to know what you want to achieve to provide a workaround... and if you are experienced with C++ — as it appears you are — you probably can come up with a strategy yourself).  All of them are probably a bit more verbose than you'd like (which I presume is what you were hoping to avoid).

Answer (score 1):

The token(s) between the `:` (if present) and the opening `{` in a scoped `enum` declaration specifies what is called – in [this Draft C++17 Standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf) – the *type-specifier-seq*:

> ##### 10.2 Enumeration declarations        [dcl.enum]
>
> …
> *enum-base:*
>       : *type-specifier-seq*

Further on in the same section, that *type-specifier-seq* is constrained as follows:

> <sup>2</sup>   … The *type-specifier-seq* of an
> *enum-base* shall name an integral type; any cv-qualification is
> ignored. …

Thus, as a reference type is *not* an integral type, it cannot be used as the "underlying type" of the `enum`.

From the same Draft Standard, the definition of "integral type" is as follows:

> ##### 6.7.1 Fundamental types       [basic.fundamental]
>
> …
> <sup>7</sup>    
> Types `bool`, `char`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, `wchar_t`, and the
> signed and unsigned integer types are collectively called *integral*
> types. A synonym for integral type is *integer type*. …

---

Note: The equivalent sections in a more-recent Draft Standard can be found [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum) `[dcl.enum]` and [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental) `[basic.fundamental]`.

Comment: FWIW you can get linkable draft standards [here](https://github.com/timsong-cpp/cppwp)

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah - I'm (slowly) moving over to using a similar online draft Standard. But the PDF version I use is eminently more searchable (to me, at least).

Comment: I do the same thing, I just like being able to link directly to the section in an answer.

Comment: Adding the tags (like `[dcl.enum]`) is something I've been doing since advised by a (former) member of the Standards Committee - that allows relatively easy tracking-down of the equivalent sections/clauses in other drafts.

Comment: Yes, definitely keep doing that, since those sections can and do move around.